# How do I make conemu open bat files on double click?

Tags: console, minecraft, conemu

I have a home-server where I run a Development minecraft server, and have moved to conemu as a CMD replacement, Exept each time I want to start the server I need to CD to the DIR & run the start.bat.
Is there a way I could create a shortcut to just double click to start the start.bat in conemu?

Comment: "cmd /?" is very helpful. /k switch?

Comment: I dont get what you mean?

Comment: Run your batch with "/k" switch.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Command line for the shortcut:

```
"C:\Program Files\Far Manager\ConEmu.exe" /cmd "\path\to\start.bat"
```

Or you could associate opening any batch file with ConEmu by modifying Windows registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Far Manager\\ConEmu.exe\" /cmd \"%1\" %*"
```

Modify ConEmu paths to match your install location.

Comment: `"C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe" "%1"` worked in my case

Comment: @knightofni but why do things the simple way?

Comment: fails to keep the terminal open with: `ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=0.
Press Enter or Esc to close console...`

Answer (score 13):

Strange but I post similar question!
No need updating registry, one of members posted an easier way:

[Running bat file easier way](https://conemu.github.io/en/DefaultTerminal.html)

We simply need selecting:

Force ConEmu as default termimal for console application

Answer (score 3):

More up to date version (for 64 bit OS) with flag to reuse the existing ConEmu instance and open a new tab:

```
"C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe" "-Reuse" "/cmd" "%1 %*"
```

Comment: Shouldn't last argument be outside the doublequotes?   like this "C:\Program Files\ConEmuPack\ConEmu64.exe" "-Reuse" "/cmd" "%1" %*                                The default was "%1" %*