# Assigning any bat file with ConEmu

Tags: batch-file

How to assign any bat file with ConEmu to window registery?

I read few suggestions at:
[Running Bat file with ConEmu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25406553/how-do-i-make-conemu-open-bat-files-on-double-click)

Here few suggestion:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Far Manager\\ConEmu.exe\" /cmd \"%1\" %*"

"C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe" "%1"

"C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe" "-Reuse" "/cmd" "%1 %*"
```

However, last comment point out that:
last argument be outside the doublequote as seen on registry:
`[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command]"%1" %*`

It seem all suggestion put all arguments with doublequote.
With provided suggestion above, can anyone confirm last argument be outside of doublequote?

Comment: How do you plan to run bat files?

Comment: How to run bat file? By double clicking those file.

Comment: Than just use DefTerm feature. https://conemu.github.io/en/DefaultTerminal.html

Comment: Ya that did it! So that I select your answer, can you move your comment to answer area?

Comment: Similar question: [How do I make conemu open bat files on double click?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25406553/873282)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default Terminal feature allows to start any console applications in ConEmu automatically.

https://conemu.github.io/en/DefaultTerminal.html

Answer (score 0):

just sample..

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DesktopBackground\Shell\downloads] @="Downloads"
>   "Position"="Bottom"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DesktopBackground\Shell\downloads\command]
>   @="explorer \"D:\Downloads\""

hope can help you!

Comment: No sure about this, can you clarify what you're saying? I can see download argument seems to be some kind directory some sort. My question how to assign any bat files ConEmu double clicking on those file (as seen on hyper link provided on question)